# Delete from table if the id doesn't exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-delete, multiple-tables

I want to delete the id's from `types` that can't be found in `types_photos` but I don't know how I can accomplish this. `id_type` in `types_photos` are the same as `id` in `types`. Here's how the table's structure looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user_added` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_user_edited` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_name` text NOT NULL,
  `data_name_seo` text NOT NULL,
  `data_type` enum('tag','equipment','search') NOT NULL,
  `datetime_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datetime_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress_added` text NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress_edited` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `types_photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user_added` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_user_edited` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_type` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_photo` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `datetime_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `datetime_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress_added` text NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress_edited` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

So, my question is; how can I delete all id's from `types` that can't be found in `types_photos`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM types 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT ID FROM types_photos
)
```

Comment: It's works like a charm! ^^ Many thanks for the quite answer. I'll accept it as soon as I can :)

Comment: @akash , I think this query is not applicable to tables that have huge number of data 'cause it's too slow. Can you suggest other query than these? Thanks.

Comment: @slek Select the records to be deleted into a temp table, perform an outer join and delete the records where the ID is null..  might work, not sure

Comment: it will not work in access, I already tried that before. by the way thanks @Akash

Comment: What if our tables have composite keys? Currently we use a table that is supposed to be a replica of a production table. Yet we do not do any deletes in case of data changes. Any advice?

Comment: @NerdinTraining  something like `WITH CTE AS (SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM types EXCEPT select c1,c2,c3 FROM types_photos ) DELETE  types FROM types  JOIN CTE c ON types.c1 = c.c1 AND types.c2=C=c2 AND types.C3=C.C3` should work, assuming c1,c2,c3 are your composite key columns